# Hypnotically disturbing

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Hypnosis means making something sleep in some sense, but what does hypnotically disturbing mean in this sentence?

> Yet the story Juniper tells that I found even more hypnotically disturbing was that of the discarded flotsam now bobbing in the oceans.

source:[theguardian](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/jan/19/what-has-nature-ever-done-for-us-tony-juniper-review)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though *hypnotic* usually evokes the sense related to sleeping, it doesn't always have to be so. Macmillan defines ***[hypnotic](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hypnotic)***, sense 1a, as "making you unable to pay attention to anything else".

So, something the author found that it was "hypnotically disturbing" would be something that was very disturbing (Juniper's story about ***the discarded flotsam now bobbing in the oceans***, according to your quote). It was disturbing enough that he (or she) couldn't focus on anything else. In other words, it was something really, really disturbing, and he (or she) couldn't ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

The entire topic of hypnosis is very interesting and being a healthcare provider, I personally love reading about it! Hypnosis **in this context** means `altered mental state` (not *mad* though). The story is so upsetting that may *disturb your mental state*. There are many types of hypnosis but here the author probably means hypnosis for a transient period.

Good discussion about [hypnosis being an altered state of consciousness](http://www-cgi.cnn.com/HEALTH/library/SA/00084.html) is here.